# plotly express heatmap using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-wrangling

I am doing some volunteer work for a South American NGO that maps criminality in the continent. It is my first time using **pandas** and I would be most grateful if you could help me with the following scenario.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Brazil', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Brazil', 'Argentina', 'Uruguay'],
                   'year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2016],
                   'occurrence': ['murder', 'murder', 'rape', 'rape', 'arson', 'arson', 'murder', 'murder', 'arson']})
```

I would like to sum the crime occurrences per country per year and display the results using a **plotly express heatmap** in which the years would be mapped to the x axis, the countries to the y axis and the colours would show the number of occurrences.

Do you think you could help me transform the data and feed it into the appropriate plotly express heatmap function?

Thank you!

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first group your data by `country` and then by `year` and count number of crimes:

```
new_df = df.groupby(["country","year"])["occurrence"].count().reset_index()
```

[image]

After that, you should change the structure of the data by pivoting the data according to your needs:

```
new_df = new_df.pivot(index='country', columns='year')['occurrence'].fillna(0)
```

[image]

Now, you can plot your heatmap:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(new_df, x=new_df.columns, y=new_df.index)
fig.update_layout(width=500,height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and answer my question.  Would you recommend any learning resources that would allow me to master concepts such as pivot, melt, unstack, etc?

Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, these concepts comes with practicing a lot of problems, but I recommend reading either books if you have time or follow some blogs on medium website about pandas.

Comment: I wanted to ask, is there anyway to add border lines to each cell?